# How can i make sure each items's margin inside a wrap panel is the same?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have an ItemsControl which has a WrapPanel as its ItemsPanelTemplate. I am trying to organise a collection of buttons so that each button has the same margin on its left and right side. Here is the code I have so far:

```
 <ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" CanContentScroll="True">
            <ItemsControl HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding SystemData.PlayersList}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Gray" Margin="5">
                            <Button Width="180"
                        Style="{Styles:MyStyleRef ResourceKey=BrowserItemStyle}">
                                <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                                    <Image Source="{Binding Icon}" Style="{Styles:MyStyleRef ResourceKey=DriveImageStyle}"/>
                                    <Label HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="{Binding Name}" Style="{Styles:MyStyleRef ResourceKey=DriveLabelStyle}"/>
                                </DockPanel>
                            </Button>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

And here is how it looks:

[image]

When i set the WrapPanel's HorizontalAlignment to 'Center' I get closer to the result i want.

[image]

I would like each Item to have the same margin either side of it so that it creates a uniform grid of controls - Is this possible?

Regards, Tim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok got it solved... I completely over looked the uniform grid control.

Here is my code now:

```
  <ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" CanContentScroll="True">
                <ItemsControl HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding SystemData.PlayersList}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <UniformGrid Columns="6"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Gray" Margin="5" Height="40">
                                <Button 
                            Style="{Styles:MyStyleRef ResourceKey=BrowserItemStyle}">
                                    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                                        <Image Source="{Binding Icon}" Style="{Styles:MyStyleRef ResourceKey=DriveImageStyle}"/>
                                        <Label HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="{Binding Name}" Style="{Styles:MyStyleRef ResourceKey=DriveLabelStyle}"/>
                                    </DockPanel>
                                </Button>
                            </Border>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </ScrollViewer>
```

[image]